# jQuery display problem?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I hide the `#changes-saved` code using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

For example let's say the code is displayed when the user clicks the submit button and then leaves the current web page and then returns back to the web page and the `#changes-saved` is no longer displayed until the submit button is clicked again.

Here is the jQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#changes-saved').hide();
    $(".save-button").click(function() {
        $.post($("#contact-form").attr("action"), $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(html) {
            $("div.contact-info-form").html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('<li>Changes saved!</li>').show().pause(1000).hide();
        });
        return false; // Prevent normal submit.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On page load keep the div hidden...

```
<div id = 'changes-saved' style='display:none'>
  some stuff
</div>
```

On button click change the div's css like...

```
$('#changes-saved').css('display','block');
```

hope this helps.. cheers...!